# C# WPF Pages - Best way to load pages

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to make a WPF UI to track shipping / receiving and inventory etc.

I have multiple pages, which will have many sup pages.

I don't want to do line per line to make them avaliable like so:

```
static public class Remote
{
    static List<IPage> Pages = new List<IPage>();

    static Remote()
    {
        Pages.Add(new pShipping());
        Pages.Add(new pReceiving());
        Pages.Add(new pInventory());
        Pages.Add(new pCustomers());
        Pages.Add(new pAdmin());
    }
}
```

As I said I really don't want to do this.  Is there a better way to navigate the pages with out pre-loading, or individually adding them to an array/list?

Comment: See if this helps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/navigation-overview

Comment: I had the same question myself earlier. I found [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/30898.simple-navigation-technique-in-wpf-using-mvvm.aspx) approach to be quite nice. You'll still have to declare data templates for the pages, but it's a slightly cleaner, more MVVM-style approach. Navigation via hyperlinks would avoid the double declaration of pages, but it wasn't relevant in my case and I don't know if it is in yours.

Comment: Thanks...kinda looks worse than how I'm doing it haha.  It's still doing it line by line:

        public NavigationViewModel()

        {

            EmpCommand = new BaseCommand(OpenEmp);

            DeptCommand = new BaseCommand(OpenDept);

        }